# change column-layout of contact form in Magento

Tags: magento

where can I change the column-layout (2-column left, 2-column right etc) of the default contact page in Magento?

thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, determine the "layout handle" for the contact page.  If [this](http://commercebugdemo.alanstorm.com/contacts/) is the page you're talking about, then your layout handle is

```
contacts_index_index
```

Next, find the layout handle in your layout.xml file

```
<contacts_index_index translate="label">
    <label>Contact Us Form</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="contacts"><title>Contact Us</title></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="contactForm" template="contacts/form.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</contacts_index_index>
```

Change the setTemplate call to reference your template

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="contacts"><title>Contact Us</title></action>
</reference>
```

Alternately, add the handle reference to your `local.xml` file.  The `local.xml` file is applied last, so whatever goes in there "wins"

```
<layout>
    <contacts_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>    
        </reference>
    </contacts_index_index>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 6):

The layout of the contact page is set in contacts.xml. So, an alternative method is:
1. Find contacts.xml in the base layout folder
2. Copy the content in that file
3. Create a new contacts.xml file in the layout folder of your template
4. Paste the content of that file and find the line that sets the default layout

```
<reference name="root">
   <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
   <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="contacts"><title>Contact Us</title></action>
</reference>
```

5. Change that line to whatever you want your default layout to be

```
<reference name="root">
   <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
   <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="contacts"><title>Contact Us</title></action>
</reference>
```

6. Save, and it overrides the default layout

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Find contacts.xml in the base layout folder, then in 41 line,

change this code from

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
```

to

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
```