# How do i fix Magento after editting app/etc/local.xml file?

Tags: magento

I need help. I added a snippet of code to the file app/etc/local.xml  and save it and ran my site and now it will not work. (here is the code i added.) [change column-layout of contact form in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314540/change-column-layout-of-contact-form-in-magento). I simply reversed the change but the site still is not working. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added a layout XML update to the `app/etc/local.xml` file, which is for updates to the global configuration tree.  These are separate systems.

The mostly likely culprit for your continued error is Magento has cached the global configuration tree.  If you're running a stock Magento, clear out all the files in

```
var/cache/*
```

and reload the page.  You should be good to go after that.

If the problem persists dig through your error logs to find the exact error Magento is throwing and let us know what it is.  Someone should be able to help you if they have that information.

Comment: Thanks clearing the files in the cache folder worked perfectly